# My Joomla Administrator Login page redirects to itself (No matter password is right or wrong)

Tags: authentication, redirect, joomla, administrator

My Joomla 3.9.1 was working fine. But now, on trying to login, the Administrator Login page redirects to itself (No matter password is right or wrong).

If password is wrong, it does not display any message.

(On local host, there is no problem)

I have updated to 3.9.14, but the issue is not resolved. Please help me.

Comment: Can you enable error reporting in joomla? What's different between your localhost and remote?

Comment: try clearing cache on the server, and if cache is enabled from your joomla configuration try turning it off and then check. Also enable the debugger as well and check what it shows.
Have you checked the 'network' tab for browser console to check the call it sends?

Comment: try placing the remote `.htaccess` file in your local project and then try and see if you're able to login to admin dashboard? Check administrator folder for any `.htaccess` file.